# VBAからvisioのShape.Nameに整数値を代入したい

Tags: vba

visioのVBAから、取得したshapeオブジェクトのNameプロパティに整数値を代入すると
原因不明の小数値も一緒に代入されてしまいます。
cStr関数を用いて代入しても結果は変わりませんでした。

`objShape.Name = 2`
上記のようにshapeオブジェクトのNameに2を代入して、オブジェクト情報を見てみると2.872が
入ってしまっています。

どのようにすれば整数値をそのまま代入することが出来ますでしょうか。

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問の件 確認してみましたが、`Visio Online` でも 
`Visio Professional 2016` でも 現象は再現しませんでした。
ちゃんと指定されたような名前に変更されました。

どのバージョンの `Visio` で発生した事象でしょうか？

たしかに `Name` だけ変更しても `NameU` が変更されないという現象が発生したので、
リンク先にあるように `Name` と `NameU` の両方を変更した方がいいようですね。

あと なぜ `Nane` に数値を入れようとしているのか気になります。
数値を設定するなら、図形データの定義で 数値の項目 `YEN` を登録して

```
vsoShape1.Cells("Prop.YEN").Formula = 26
```

のような使い方をする方が Visio では一般的のような気がします。

図形に紐づいた情報を管理するのはその方がいろいろ設定できるので便利だと思います。

以下の 回答は参考までに残しておきます。

### 追記前の情報

一番近い参考になりそうな資料は
[how-can-i-change-the-name-of-the-shape](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-visio/how-can-i-change-the-name-of-the-shape-in/9e355d44-386c-4c13-8a90-54cb30785dc3)
かな・・。

Name と NameU の両方を変更するようです。

[NameU](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/visio.shape.nameu)　
は ローカライズされていない方の名前で

```
シェイプシートでは、セルの数式と値に汎用名だけが表示されます。
```

とマニュアルに書かれているので、 汎用名=NameU の方も変更してみてください。

手元に確認する環境がないので、参考程度で・・。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。

ご教授頂いたようにNameUに同様の数値を入れてもオブジェクト情報の名前には小数点付の数値が入ってしまっていました。

対応として、str関数で空文字付の数値を代入することにするか、
あるいはご指摘いただいたように"Prop.YEN"に数値を代入するように変更することを検討してみます。

Comment: 参考のため、できたらVisioのバージョンと結果どうなったかなを、時間のあるときにコメントください。

Comment: 環境はvisio 2007です。
うまく数値が代入が出来ない原因は、他のShapeのNameプロパティに同様の値が設定されているためという、いたって初歩的なミスでした。
Nameプロパティは一意のものでなければならないということを知りませんでした。
お手数おかけしました。

Comment: 本当ですね。ドローイングエクスプローラーの上で 図形の名前を変更した場合、同じ名前がある場合に 自動的にぶつからないように名前の番号が変更されるのを確認しました。`Visio 2017`。エクセルのSharp は Name プロパティーに同じ値が設定できるようなので Visio 独自の動作なんでしょうね。 私も知りませんでした。マニュアルには載っていない 仕様なんでしょうね。